# Is it possible to get the envelope of a signal via FIR filter?

Tags: finite-impulse-response, envelope

I was reading an article about ultrasonic signals, and I read in it that it is possible to get the envelope of a signal by using a band pass FIR filter.
My question: **Is it possible to get the envelope of a signal by passing it through a band pass FIR filter?**
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the envelope of a signal requires more than a simple band-pass filter.

However, you could rectify the signal and bandpass-filter the rectified signal to get the enveloppe. That's how I used to do it with ultrasound signals.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector

You could also use more elaborate techniques, like the Hilbert transform (or Hilbert filter) to get a complex signal that would allow use to use the modulus (or magnitude) of the complex signal to get the envelope.